# What exactly does the rail upgrade do?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I've got the thing on my Multi-tool, and it paired "green" with the mining stuff instead of "red" with the boltcaster stuff.

I feel like I'm killing Sentinels faster with the mining beam now, but that might be anecdotal from all the other upgrades I did in that session.

Does anyone have any legit observations, instead of anecdotes or "I think the flavor text means X"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rail adapter seems to be a general purpose power boost for the mining beam (which is why it counts as a green mining upgrade instead of a red boltcaster upgrade). It makes you mine significantly faster, and also destroys sentinels quicker as well.

However, this extra "oomph" comes with a price. While the rail adapter is used, the mining beam will overheat much faster than normal, meaning you either need to add several cooldown upgrades or you have to space out its use into pulses (to abuse the heat reset bug). Additionally, it only fires in a straight line, meaning that you have to aim more precisely during combat.

Comment: It's definitely confusing though, as if I remember correctly, the tooltip labels it as a Boltcaster upgrade, despite it affecting the mining beam.

Comment: Ok, I hadn't noticed the faster overheating because I had put multiple upgrade on at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

From what I've read, it changes the behavior of the mining tool to be more like the laser on your starship. High power, low usability.

What it does:

> increases the speed of your projectile to instantly damage the target

As MageXY pointed out, this modification causes the mining tool to overheat very quickly, which would make actually mining with it less efficient.

Source: http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/739857-no-mans-sky/74155237

Comment: I'm not sure I'd count some forum posts as objective evidence. In fact, I happen to disagree with the posts strongly: I personally much prefer a juiced up homing boltcaster for combat. It allows me to hit harder, faster, and for a longer period of time, and I can hit things accurately even from a long distance thanks to the homing bullets.

Comment: Well the question asked for observations, but I have not personally used it, so I googled it and it sounded like combat wise, the rail gun mod for the mining laser gives it more DPS than a boltcaster.

Comment: I think it depends on the upgrades. The railgun adapter definitely makes the beam overheat faster, so while the raw numbers might indicate the damage is higher for the railgun, you have to stop shooting for several seconds every now and then to wait until your beam cools down. This also applies while mining, which IMO gets very annoying.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't sound like something that's conducive to mining but combat wise, for sure. I wasn't aware of the cooldown, but that would definitely sway my opinion if I was the one making a decision.